# Automator in Mavericks freezes when creating or opening a Folder Action

Tags: macos, mac, freeze, osx-mavericks, automator

Short version: On an older Mac, Automator hangs when trying to create a Folder Action.

---

I have an older Mac being used as a media server.  It is a Core 2 Duo iMac with 3 GB of memory, running Mavericks.  (It is slow, but works well as an iTunes/iPhoto/Backblaze machine.) It has a few services running in the background all the time: Backblaze, Google Drive, Dropbox, and Splashtop, which I mention in case any of these might be causing trouble.

I am trying to create an Automator Folder Action that monitors ~/Dropbox/Camera Uploads and imports the  images to iPhoto, and then deletes them. This should be straightforward.

However, as soon as I select a folder for the "Folder Action" in Automator, Automator hangs.  That is, I can select "Folder Action" from the initial dialog screen, but choosing *any* folder for the action freezes Automator.  I have tried various folders, and I have also tried deleting the preferences file for Automator.  No luck.

As a workaround, I tried creating the Folder Action on another Mac, where it worked, saving it to iCloud, and opening it on the media server Mac.  But doing this freezes Automator on the media server Mac, as well.

I would appreciate any assistance in making it so that I can create and run Folder Actions on the media server Mac, or, alternatively, a way (besides Hazel, which is a little expensive for this one task) to automatically import photos in a folder into iPhoto and then delete them from the folder.